# JMeter BeanShell Assertion can't identify FileUtil methods

Tags: jar, set, jmeter, external, beanshell

I have written a code to do DIFF of two text files in Java/Eclipse using 
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils and Set operations. The code is working fine.
but the same code is not working in JMeter's BeanShell Assertion.
Lines with Set operations giving error.
Code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
Date startdate = new Date();
Date enddate = null;
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Work//JMeter//Logs//D2MDS.txt")));
out.println("Automated ETL Validator -- START -- " + dateFormat.format(startdate));
out.println("=========================================================================");

try {
Set<String> Slines = new TreeSet<String>(FileUtils.readLines(new File ("C://Work//JMeter//Data//SourceSQLLog.csv")));
//Set<String> Tlines = new TreeSet<String>(FileUtils.readLines(new File ("C://Work//JMeter//Data//TargetSQLLog.csv")));
//Slines.removeAll(Tlines);
//out.println(Slines);
}
catch (Exception e) {
out.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
}

Date enddate = new Date();
enddate = new Date();
long duration  = enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime();
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);

out.println("=========================================================================");
out.println("Automated ETL Validator  -- END --  " + dateFormat.format(enddate));
out.println("\n\n\n*************************************************************************");
out.println("EXECUTION SUMMARY");
out.println("====================");
out.println("Total Lines in  Extract File: " + ${__V(ret_val_#)});
out.println("Total Failures in Extract File: " + fail_cnt);
out.println("Failed Lines of Extract File = " + fail_ln);
out.println("Extract Validation -- END -- " + dateFormat.format(enddate) + "  -- Duration: " + diffInMinutes + " Minutes");
out.close();
```

Beanshell Assertion is throwing obscure error:

```
Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; import java.io.*; import java.util.Date; . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 18, column 20.
```

5 Jar files are present inside JMeter's /lib folder. How do I make JMeter recognize the Set methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

It isn't connected with FileUtils class usage, the fault point is line 18 as per

> Encountered "=" at line 18, column 20.

Change your line #18 from

```
Date enddate = new Date();
```

to

```
enddate = new Date();
```

as you have already defined it at line #3 Beanshell interpreter fails to parse line 18 as the variable is present in this scope.

**Second**

Beanshell is not Java so

```
Set<String> Slines = new TreeSet<String>
```

will also fail. You will need to remove diamond brackets

```
Set Slines = new TreeSet...
```

**Third:**

Also I don't see where `fail_cnt` and `fail_ln` are defined and would suggest to substitute

```
${__V(ret_val_#)}
```

with

```
vars.get("ret_val_#");
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for Beanshell-related tips and tricks.

Hope this helps.